# LinearLayoutManager#scrollToPositionWithOffset() not working sometimes

Tags: android, material-design

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
 super.onResume();
 recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).scrollToPositionWithOffset(position, viewTopDistance);
  }
 });
}
```

position and viewTopDistance are saved and persisted correctly when the user clicks a view which launches another activity. Upon return to the recycler view about 2/3 of the time the list looks correct, the other 1/3 of the times it just shows the first 4 or 5 times at the top (scrollToPositionWithOffset didn't work)

Any ideas on why this fails sometimes?

Answer (score 5):

I believe your problem is in timing. Although 'post' delays 'scrollToPositionWithOffset', the view may not be always ready. I use the following construct.

```
  mLstView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreDraw() {
      if (mLstView.getChildCount() > 0) {
        recyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);   
        llMgr.scrollToPositionWithOffset(position, viewTopDistance);  
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
  });
```

with success (so far).  You may also look at the [demo code](https://github.com/seanpjanson/SQListRecycler) that implements this construct (LstFrag.select).

Good Luck

Comment: I have found multiple suggestions on StackOverflow for this, and this is the only one that works reliably.